# Removing Duplicate entries from query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to remove **ALL** identical Barcodes so i only have unique barcodes left.
How can I do that?

My query attributes are these:

```
SELECT 
    Barcode, DeliveryAdrID
FROM 
    dbo.Sending
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: What would that achieve?

Comment: And why do you need to ask? You already have the query... does it not work? Not return the right data? Then what would the *right data* be? Show us the table contents and the output you're looking for!

Comment: This will get distinct on both Barcode and DeliveryAdrID i only want it to get distinct barcodes

Comment: @Lahib: no it results distinct combinations: like 111, 1; 111,2; 222, 1; 222,2;

Comment: Exactly and i need only to get Distinct Barcode and One DeliveryAdrID

Comment: How should the `DeliveryAdrId` be determined? You only need one, you say, but **which** one?

Comment: The thing is that some of our deliveries are delivered to a wrong address. Im searching for all Barcodes that are delivered to a wrong address. but some of these barcodes are identical for some reason. So one barcode which duplicated in the table has different deliveryAdrID's. So actually i dont need to get distinct but to Remove **ALL** identical Barcodes. So i only have unique barcodes. Does that make sense ?

Comment: But you say that you want to show a DeliveryAdrId for each distinct barcode. How do you determine which one of multiple DeliveryAdrId is the correct one for each barcode?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I want to remove every row with a Barcode that has a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want Barcode once, and some DeliveryAdrID value to go with it

```
  SELECT Barcode, MIN(DeliveryAdrID) OneOfDeliveryAdrID
    FROM dbo.Sending
GROUP BY Barcode;
```

This allows a result set like:

```
Barcode  | OneOfDeliveryAdrID
ABCDEF     123
XYZ        123
PPP        123
ABC123     456
BARCODE    789
```

i.e. each barcode will only appear once (DISTINCT) but multiple barcodes could end up with the same DeliveryAdrID.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you tell me how to remove **ALL** duplicate barcodes?

Comment: Remove from the displayed results - the answer does that already.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Id filed in your table ?

So , you can try :

```
select Barcode, DeliveryAdrID
from dbo.Sending s
where Id >= all
(
 select Id
 from dbo.Sending
 where Barcode=s.Barcode
)
```

Hope I understand what you try to do...

Answer (score 0):

This is what i was looking for.

```
SELECT Barcode, MIN(DeliveryAdrID)as DeliveryAdrID
    FROM dbo.Sending
GROUP BY Barcode
Having count(Barcode)=1
```